# DatePicker doesn't bind value in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, datepicker, blazor

I'm using date picker in my component to bind the value to my method in blazor. the value is always empty.

Here is my component :

```
  <input data-provide="datepicker" class="col-sm-2 form-control" @bind="date_selected" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
        style="width: 300x ;height:35px;">

code{
    string date_selected;


    public async Task GetTags()
    {
        AllTags = await Task.Run(() => tagsService.Map( date_selected));

    }

}
```

my java script :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({ 
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'
    });
    $("#from-datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var fromdate = $(this).val();
        alert(fromdate);
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea why I can't get the values and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I suppose you can do it with pure Blazor.  Maybe something like:

```
<input type="date" @onchange=HandledateChange />
<div>You selected: @date</div>

@code {
    string date = "";

    async Task HandledateChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        date = args.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same problem and it is not working for me :(

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093208/could-not-set-or-bind-model-property-with-bootstrap-datepicker-in-blazor

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  What do you want? Are you trying to convert a date input to a C# type?  What, exactly, have you tried?