# Could not set or bind model property with Bootstrap Datepicker in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, datepicker, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using bootstrap datepicker and the problem is that when I pick a date, it does not fire a change or input event and noting is binding with the model property `Course.StartDate` or `Course.EndDate`.
The default datepicker works but does not support Afghanistan datetime. That is why I use boostrap datepicker.

Blazor code:

```razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
@using myproject.Data
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject myproject.Repository.CoursesRepository _coursesRepository

@inject IJSRuntime JS

<EditForm Model="@Course" OnValidSubmit="e=> { if(selectedId == 0) { addCourse(); } else { updateCourse(Course.CourseId); } }">
<div class="mb-2">
    <div>@Course.StartDate</div>
    <label class="col-form-label" for="StartDate">@Loc["Start Date"]<span class="text-danger fs--1">*</span>:</label>
    <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="Course.StartDate" @bind-Value:format="yyyy-MM-dd" id="StartDate" />
    <ValidationMessage class="text-danger" For="(() => Course.StartDate)"/>
</div>

<div class="mb-2">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="EndDate">@Loc["End Date"]<span class="text-danger fs--1">*</span>:</label>
    <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="Course.EndDate" @bind-Value:format="yyyy-MM-dd" id="EndDate"/>
    <ValidationMessage class="text-danger" For="(() => Course.EndDate)"/>
</div>
</EditForm>
@code {

  public CourseModel Course = new();
  public string[] dates = new string[] { "#StartDate", "#EndDate" };
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        loadScripts();
    }

    void addCourse()
    {
        _coursesRepository.AddCourse(Course);
        FillData();
        Course = new();
        var title = "Course";
        Swal.Success(title : Loc[$"{title} added successfully"],toast : true);

    }
    // initializes the datepicker
    public async Task loadScripts()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeDatepicker", (object) dates);
    }

}
```

This is script for initializing the datepickers

```js
<script>
    function initializeDatepicker(dates) {
        dates.forEach((element) => {
                $(element).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText) {
                    // this is not working
                    element.value = this.value;
                    /* 
                      tried this and still not working
                      $(element).trigger("change");
                      also tried this and still not working
                      $(element).change();
                    */
                    // this is working
                    console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
                },
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true

            });
        });
           
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check the @bind-event:onchange maybe its worked

Comment: Hi @Najeeb Anwari, in blazor, it is quite different from asp.net core application. It will not automatically trigger the js event. You need trigger it manually by JSRuntime.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the changes are made with JavaScript and so the page state does not change for Blazor, in other words, Blazor does not notice the value change at all.

To solve this problem, you must inform the Blazor component of the changes by calling a C# method inside the JavaScript function. For this, you can use the `DotNet.invokeMethodAsync` built-in dotnet method. As follows:

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ProjectAssemblyName', 'ComponentMethod', this.value.toString())
```

Its first argument is the assembly name of your project. The second argument is the name of the C# function that you  will write in the component, and finally, the third argument is the selected date value.
The method called in C# should be as follows:

```
static string selectedDate;
[JSInvokable]
public static void ComponentMethod(string pdate)
{
    selectedDate = pdate;
}
```

This method must be decorated with [JSInvokable] and must be static.

I have done the same thing for another javascript calendar in Persian language. Its codes are available in [the `JavaScriptPersianDatePickerBlazor` repository](https://github.com/Kamalifar/JavaScriptPersianDatePickerBlazor).
You can also create a custom calendar in the form of a component so that you can use it more easily in all components in any formats that you want such as `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` or string and so on. There is an example of this in [the `AmibDatePickerBlazorComponent` repository](https://github.com/Kamalifar/AmibDatePickerBlazorComponent).